# Compare two Excel columns A&B and add in one cell the data of a third column C of the entries not present in A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three columns, two of them are a list of countries. The third column is a list of numbers corresponding to the countries in column A. The formula should compare column A and C and add in a single cell the numbers of the countries not present in list C when compared to A. I want the output to be only one cell, not a list. I've tried with Index & Match and with a Sumproduct and Sumif but I haven't been able to make it work, maybe my syntax was bad. Thanks!

```
A               B       C         Output  
Austria         1000    Belgium   6000  
Belgium         2000    Spain   
Spain           3000    Portugal  
Portugal        4000  
United Kingdom  5000
```

Answer (score 2):

In **E1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,C:C,0)),B1,0)
```

and  copy down.  Then in **D1** enter:

```
=SUM(E:E)
```

[image]

*It is possible to use an **array formula** and avoid helper-column **E**, but for long columns, it would be slow.*

For example, the array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A:A,C:C,0)),B:B,0))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking real long about it and couldn't find the answer!

Comment: @Michthan  You are quite welcome..............if possible, use the helper-column approach..............